# Checking if key exist in NSDictionary at first and second level

Tags: objective-c

I have two different dataset but need to check if dictionary has emp_id or not in the two given dictionary. I could not know how to handle the second level dictionary check in the given dataset

```
NSDictionary *data = nil;

NSDictionary *data = @{@"emp_id" : @"123456"};

NSDictionary *data = @{@"emp_id" : @{@"emp_id" : @"123456"}}; 

BOOL isEmpExist = [data containsObjectForKey :@"emp_id"]; // works for the first example

BOOL isSecondLevelExist = [data containsObjectForKey :@"emp_id"] 
                           containsObjectForKey@"emp_id"]; // crashes if we have one level data

if (isEmpExist) {
    // yes found
}else {
    // not found!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *data1 = @{@"emp_id" : @"123456"};

NSDictionary *data2 = @{@"emp_id" : @{@"emp_id" : @"123456"}};
```

(I've renamed these two variables from your question so that I can refer to each one directly.)

Notice that in `data1`, the value of `emp_id` is an `NSString`. In `data2`, the value of the outer `emp_id` is an `NSDictionary`. So there are four possibilities:

1. There is no outer `emp_id` (thus no inner `emp_id`).
2. There is an outer `emp_id`, but its value is not an `NSDictionary` (thus no inner `emp_id`).
3. There is an outer `emp_id`, and its value is an `NSDictionary`, but that dictionary doesn't contain `emp_id`.
4. There is an outer `emp_id`, and its value is an `NSDictionary`, and that dictionary contains an `emp_id`.

I think it's easier to handle the cases in a slightly different order in code:

```
id outerValue = data[@"emp_id"];
if (outerValue == nil) {
    // case 1: outer emp_id does not exist, inner emp_id cannot exist
} else if ([outerValue isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.self]) {
    id innerValue = [outerValue objectForKey:@"emp_id"];
    if (innerValue == nil) {
        // case 3: outer emp_id exists, inner emp_id does not
    } else {
        // case 4: outer emp_id exists, inner emp_id also exists
    }
} else {
    // case 2: outer emp_id exists, inner emp_id cannot exist
}
```